# Spatial relationship between fast ice and frazil ice using heat maps

Tags: mapping, statistics

I used Google Earth Engine to create heat maps for both frazil ice frequency and fast ice frequency. This was done by classifying these ice types from MODIS images along the Victoria Land Coast in Antarctica, every day in January and February, from 2005 to 2023. I then converted the classified images to binary, with the pixel values classified as these ice types being 1 and everything else being 0. Then I created the heat maps by summing the pixels of these binary images, dividing this by the total number of images (taking cloudy images into account), and multiplying this by 100. The pixel values represent the percentage/ frequency at which these ice types are present at a given point in space, over this period of time.

I want to look at the spatial relationship between fast ice and frazil ice. What is a good statistical method I could use to determine whether frazil ice forms close to fast ice using the heat maps of both these ice types? It’s more about closeness than overlap, as you’re not going to detect frazil ice in the same location as fast ice on a single image – there would often be an inverse relationship there, as they don’t occupy the same space simultaneously.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Asking suggestions about problems is considered opinion-based in this site and may get closed. If you are facing any problem while implementing any method in a GIS tool (software or programming language), you can ask here. Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)